# vim uses /tmp for shell functions

Tags: vim

When vim uses the shell given a colon !command, it does so through the /tmp filesystem. How do you force vim to use ~/.vim/tmp/ instead? It also uses /tmp for help files when zcat is required to read some of the manuals.

TMPDIR doesn't work for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable?  That's the standard way (across most "Unix style" programs I've had to worry about it for) of specifying an alternate location for temporary files.

Comment: Actually, this works. I was thinking you were referring to vim's 'directory' setting. Thanks.

Comment: I've clarified my wording to make it clear I was referring to the env var.